# Is there a Cognito SDK that uses the `amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token` endpoint?

Tags: amazon-cognito

Accoding to the following docs, I can exchange a `code` for an `access_token` using this curl:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://mysubdomain.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'authorization: Basic ...' \
  -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=client_id&code=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somewhere.com'
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

I got this working no problem in Postman. Now I want to replicate this HTTP request in a dotnet core WebApi application and I'm having a very hard time finding any SDK to manage this. I could build and issue HttpRequest + deserialize the response json to models, but I find it hard time believing there isn't some AWS library that handles and maintains this much better than I ever could.

Is there an SDK for the `amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token` endpoint, preferably for dotnet core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not yet. You should use make a native HTTP call with POST method.

Here is the git issue for the same (for Java):

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1792